# Function in drools rule file

Tags: drools

I have a simple POJO, which has a String field

```
   public class InputFilter {
    String email;
    }
```

And this is the DRL file

```
   function void printEmail(String email) {
      System.out.println(email);
     }

    rule "PrintEmail"
    when
       InputPayload(eval(printEmail(inputFilter.email)))
    then
    end
```

Here I get the error as

```
text=Rule Compilation error inputFilter.email cannot be resolved to a type
```

This should be simple. I am not sure what I am missing here. I have imported all the required classes. Also, it can understand the type when I do something like `inputFilter.email != null`.

Comment: Shouldn't you have "public" in front of String email; in your InputFilter class?

Comment: My bad, I have it as public. This is the piece of the code from original POJO and I missed the access modifier to mention here.